# multiple monthly averages for multiple years using sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am having a data set in the format which i'm attaching below. It contains data for, say, 25 years on a daily basis. I have to take out averages of each column (AA, BB, CC,DD) omitting null values, for a single / multiple months (not all months together) year wise: like avg of AA for the month of Jan and Jul from 90-95. I'm not able to frame a proper query.

```
NAME    DD  MM  YYYY    TIME    AA  BB  CC  DD

DLH     01  01  1986    0000    0           
DLH     01  01  1986    0100    0           
DLH     01  01  1986    0200    0           
DLH     01  01  1986    0230    0   6   5   94

DLH     01  01  1986    0300    0           
DLH     01  01  1986    0400    0           
DLH     01  01  1986    0500    0           
DLH     01  01  1986    0530    0   6   5   94

DLH     01  01  1986    0600    0   6       
DLH     01  01  1986    0700    0   6       
DLH     01  01  1986    0800    0   8       
DLH     01  01  1986    0830    0   9   8   95

DLH     01  01  1986    0900    0   9       
DLH     01  01  1986    1000    2   14      
DLH     01  01  1986    1100    2   17      
DLH     01  01  1986    1115    5           
DLH     01  01  1986    1130    7   17  9   60

DLH     01  01  1986    1140    7           
DLH     01  01  1986    1145    7           
DLH     01  01  1986    1150    7           
DLH     01  01  1986    1200    8   18      
DLH     01  01  1986    1300    6   18      
DLH     01  01  1986    1400    10  18      
DLH     01  01  1986    1430    7   18  8   50
```

Comment: are you using mysql or sql server,also please post required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question properly, I would do the following for the example given:

```
SELECT AVG(x.AA)
FROM 
    (SELECT AA
    FROM Table1
    WHERE MM IN (1,7) AND YYYY BETWEEN 1990 AND 1995) x
```